# При попытке добавить новую запись в базу данных выдает ошибку

Tags: php, mysql

При попытке добавить новую запись в базу данных выдает ошибку и не выводит кнопку удаления записей

```
<?php

require_once 'login.php';
$db_server = mysql_connect($db_hostname, $db_username);
if (!$db_server) die("Невозможно подключиться к MySQL: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($db_database, $db_server)

    or die("Невозмонжо выбрать базу данных: " . mysql_error());

if (isset($_POST['delete']) && isset($_POST['isbn']))
{
    $isbn = get_post('isbn');
    $query = "DELETE FROM classics WHERE isbn='$isbn'";

    if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "Сбой при удалении данных: $query<br>" .

        mysql_error() . "<br><br>";

}

if (isset($_POST['author']) &&
    isset($_POST['title']) &&
    isset($_POST['category']) &&
    isset($_POST['year']) &&
    isset($_POST['isbn']))

{
    $author = get_post('author');
    $title = get_post('title');
    $category = get_post('category');
    $year = get_post('year');
    $isbn = get_post('isbn');

    $query = "INSERT INTO classics VALUES" . 

    "('$author', '$title, '$category, '$year, '$isbn')";
    if (!mysql_query($query, $db_server))
        echo "Сбой при вставке данных: $query<br>" . 
        mysql_error() . "<br><br>";
}

echo <<<_END
<form action="sqltest.php" method="post"><pre>
Author <input type="text" name="author">
Title <input type="text" name="title">
Category <input type="text" name="category">
Year <input type="text" name="year">
Isbn <input type="text" name="isbn">
<input type="submit" value="ADD RECORD">
</pre></form>
_END;

$query = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) die ("Сбой при доступе к базе данных: " . mysql_error());


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

for ($j = 0 ; $j < $rows ; ++$j)

{
    $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);
    echo <<<_END
    <pre>
    Author $row[0]
    Title $row[1]
    Category $row[2]
    Year $row[3]
    ISBN $row[4]
    </pre>
    <form action="sqltest.php method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="delete" value="yes">
    <input type="hidden" name="isbn" value="$row[4]"
    <input type="submit" value="DELETE RECORD"></form>
_END;
}

mysql_close($db_server);
function get_post($var)
{
    return mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
}

?>
```

Comment: Если не сложно, дополните вопрос текстом ошибки?

Comment: Сбой при вставке данных: INSERT INTO classics VALUES('', ', ', ', '')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', '')' at line 1

Comment: поставьте пробел после `VALUES`

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"('$author', '$title, '$category, '$year, '$isbn')";
```

Ваша ошибка в sql-запросе, как минимум не хватает кавычек на параметрах:

```
"('$author', '$title', '$category', '$year', '$isbn')";
```

Во-вторых, т.к. в запросе вы не указываете явно поля, то в `values()` нужно передавать все. Если в табличке, например, присутствует поле id, то учитывайте это в запросе.

В-третьих, ваш запрос подвержен sql-инъекциям. Советовал бы использовать mysqli или pdo и плэйсхолдеры для вставки переменных.